# Reccommendation letter after unsuccessful probationary period

Tags: recommendation-letter

For various professional reasons (basically we were not a fit in our ways of working) yesterady I was told I would not pass my probationary period. I was given a reccommendation letter though. Here it is, what do you think of it? Would this be seen as a "good" reccomendation letter"?:

"Mr. Perdices had good professional knowledge of his area of expertise, especially in molecular biology.
While becoming familiar with his new field of work, he always showed strong initiative and eagerness to
learn. He connected new things with what he already knew and set himself high professional standards.
Mr. Perdices was a reliable and goal-oriented employee, who implemented planned onboarding tasks with
a high level of motivation and good quality results.
​
The conduct of Mr. Perdices towards managers and peers was always friendly, transparent, and honest.
He actively shared work-related information and knowledge with the team and always showed a
collaborative approach.
Mr. Perdices leaves our company today. We would like to thank Mr. Perdices for his contributions during
the last months and wish him all the very best for the future."

Comment: VTC as opinion based/cannot really help you with anything here. On related info note, getting a reference letter for failing probation is on its own darn good. It doesn't say anything untowards either, so not much to hate there either.

Comment: Opinion based. That said, my opinion is that it's a good letter.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Is this highly codified language as for example References in in Germany or Austria, or is it to be taken as plain English at face value?

Comment: Mmmh, it might be a bit of both, since the reference letter comes from a business in the German part of Switzerland, but it has been written in plain English. Is there any codifiable German answer in the structure I should be aware of here?

Answer (score 3):

Is this good? Well, "good" is a relative term so it is tough to say. In my opinion, this is a reasonable and positive letter of recommendation given that you failed your probationary period. If I were your manager, I would not have provided any letter of recommendation so I think you should take this as a win. With that being said, I would suggest that you focus more on the issues that caused you to fail probation than this letter. Good luck.

Comment: There are reasons that someone can fail a probationary period that don't have to do with the person's ability.  I know plenty of good engineers who would be bad fits at different companies I've worked for.  In the scenario, it's best for all parties to separate, and no reason not to give a good recommendation just because of a difference in philosophy (and for that matter, the manager may even agree but have no ability to change it).